# AngularJS dinamically change a select css class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

i want to change dinamically the appearance of a select component as selected option changes in angularjs.

This is my markup

```
<select id="actionType" ng-class="$ctrl.pdaProject.actionType.color" ng-options="::(option.code + ' - ' +option.description) for option in $ctrl.actionTypes | orderBy:'code' track by option.code name="actionType" ng-model="$ctrl.pdaProject.actionType" class="editable-input form-control input-sm multicolor" required>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

The `$ctrl.pdaProject.actionType.color` contains a css class name.
Example of a color class

```
.mark-yellow {
        background-color:#FEE715;
        color: #101820;
}
```

Once selected i want the page change the appearance of the select, but it doesn't happen until the select loose focus.

Instead using the style attribute directly and setting up the background works well.

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add in this way:

```
[ngClass]="records.length > 0 ? 'fas fa-angle-down' : 'fas fa-angle-up'"
```

You can add a condition as per your requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure youre answering to my question ? I was asking how to change the css with my css style and WITHOUT the need to blur my html component